# jQuery with Sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, sharepoint-2007

I would like to use the jQuery lib with a Sharepoint 2007 application. I read this article here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2008/11/20/sharepoint-2007-and-jquery-1.aspx

which talks about giving access to the web part controls through publishing a feature that will add the delegate control containing the script tag to load the .js file. I am having hard time understanding:

a. Which manifest file I have to modify to include this:

```
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Control
    Id="AdditionalPageHead"
    ControlSrc="~/_controltemplates/jQueryControl ascx />
 </Elements>
```

b. What exactly needs to be done so that all of my controls residing in
c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\template\controltemplates\myCompany\myApp
will have access to the plug in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the Sharepoint SmartTools from codeplex to register jquery with Sharepoint.